# What is displayed in the ''task'' column of the ''Window Task Manager"

Tags: delphi

I have a delphi application called ''UCS1''. The main form caption displays the application name, an instance number an a file name, as for example:

UCS1 - [1] all.txt

In the Window Task Manager, the application is listed exactly as the caption of the main form, which is OK. Hoovering on the task bar, shows also the caption of the main form.

I have another application called ''CTT'', the main form caption displays the same elements as in the UCS1 application, for example:

CTT - [1] afile.txt

However, when displayed in the Windows Task Manager, the application appears as ''Ctt'', and when hoovering on the task bar it also shows ''Ctt''.

I know that ''Ctt'' is the Application instance title (ModuleName).

The two applications are compiled with the same Delphi (10.3). What could be the reason of not displaying both application the same way in the Windows Task Manager, i.e. as the caption of the main form.

These are vcl applications, I've seen this behavior on W7.

Comment: Compare Application.Title to your Mainform.Caption?

Comment: .. and Application.MainFormOnTaskbar.

Comment: IOW, what is displayed is the caption of the window that has the taskbar button. This is the hidden application window if MainFormOnTaskbar is false. Otherwise it is the same with VCL main form. The caption of the hidden application window is given by Application.Title.

Comment: yes, what @SertacAkyuz said :)

Comment: I can't find a "task" column in the task manager I am looking at.

Comment: @David - There are some pictures of the Windows 7 task manager [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/the-windows-8-task-manager).

Comment: Ugh, Windows 7, we don't do that anymore in my world!

Comment: I can confirm that the situation is the same under W10: Hovering on the task bar on the CTT application icon displays ''Ctt'' and over the USC1 icon it displays ''UCS1 [1] file.txt''. ''Ctt'' is the module name (of the application instance), ''UCS1 [...].....'' is the caption of the main form.

Comment: This information is probably read out of the version resource

Comment: I have no idea why is not my comment convincing..

Comment: @Sertac: Yes your (short) comment is completely correct, thank you. I guess that the statement ''MainFormOnTaskBar := true;'' has been added automatically to the dpr file after the 'CTT'' application was created and therefore it was missing in that application. Now, both appllcations behave the same.

Comment: @caymon - You're welcome. The other one is also accurate for Windows 7. Can't tell for later OS though..